# Cart page displays the price and amount as zero regardless of price entered

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

The site I am currently working on has a pay your price feature that allows customers to enter the amount they wish to pay for rent and such. Once they enter the amount and some additional information they click the add to cart button and it directs them to the cart page. On this page however, the price and amount are zero regardless of amount that they entered. Any insight or advise into the cause and solution of this issue would be greatly appreciated. For reference site is stlcitywide.com (make a payment feature)

additional info:
after additional troubleshooting it appears to be an issue with the regular price. Whatever the regular price is defined as on the product page as an admin, that is the price the cart will display, and if no price is defined then the cart is empty. So it seems the cart is only looking for the regular price and is not seeing the minimum or user inputted value.

Comment: 2 things, are you sure the price is correctly add to the cart session with the right action and if it's the case, you maybe need to calculate totals once again by using a filter when you redirect user to the cart, try WC()->cart->calculate_totals(); with template_redirect action (check if it's the cart page in the callback function).

Comment: I am not super familiar with the woocommerce functions but I will look into it. That was kind of my feeling that the cart for some reason is not pulling in the value added on the payment screen. any idea how I would go about checking if that value is being pulled, or where in the source code I should look at least.

Answer (score 1):

That's maybe not really the right anwser, but the way to test if prices are pulled into the cart and the way to recalculate cart totals.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'test_cart_values');

function test_cart_values(){
    $cart_items = WC()->cart->get_cart();
    if(is_cart() || is_checkout() ){
        var_dump($cart); 
        foreach($cart_items as $item){
            if($item['line_subtotal'] == '' or $item['line_subtotal'] == 0){
                $calculate_once_again = true;
            }
        }
        if($calculate_once_again == true){
            WC()->cart->calculate_totals();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you can get the cart from session in an other way.
Remove var_dump() if you are on a production server.

Hope it helps

Comment: ok, and maybe a stupid question but where would i add this code. Would I add it to the woocommerce cart.php file itself or as a separate hook on that particular page.

Comment: To the functions.php file of your child theme 

Comment: This created a 500 internal service error.

Comment: $item['line_subtotal must be $item['line_subtotal'] , sorry that was a mistake, i correct my answer

Comment: yea I should have caught that, but it did not resolve the issue. There were several updates made to the template files as well as to plugins recently so i am thinking it is some php error (i checked if there was any conflicting third party plugins and there wasn't). The cart and and the checkout page are both registering as zero, which leads me to think that the payment value is never making it to the cart.

Comment: Without your code it's hard to tell you... Remove my code and check your browser console to see if there's no ajax error on Post request (when you press add to cart).

Comment: there were no errors. Its has something to do with the cart only reading the "regular price" defined on the product page.